# Exception: java.lang.NoclassDefFoundError: java/util/jar/pack200

Tags: netbeans, ide, instalacion

Tengo Instalada la última versión de Jdk(14) que me pide. Al ejecutar el programa Apache-NetBeans-11.3-bin-windows-x64 me tira el siguiente error:

> Critical Error An unexpected exception happened in thread main
>   Exception:  java.lang.NoclassDefFoundError:  java/util/jar/pack200

Si alguien me puede ayudar le agradeceria

Comment: Echa un vistazo a https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour para ver cómo puedes mejorar tus preguntas y tener mayor posibilidad de respuesta.  Ese tipo de error puede ser por una mala configuración de tu JDK. Prueba con una versión JDK 8 y/o verifica que ese Netbeans es compatible con el JDK instalado.

Comment: para resolover el problema es que desinstales la version 14 del jdk, netbeans lo rechaza, utilizaa el jdk 13.0.2

Comment: @DanielJS no es solución desinstalar, puede instalar otra versión y configurarla desde Netbeans.

Comment: Estoy en la misma situación que tú, en mi caso me aparece: "unexpected exception happened in thread main. Exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java/util/jar/Pack200" Aún no encuentro solución, pero por lo menos no estás solo:(

Comment: No di con la solución, pero descargué NetBeans 8, adjunto link.
https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/es/java/javase/downloads/index.html
y me va perfecto, ya no te es de utilidad por el tiempo transcurrido por lo visto, pero de igual forma, si le sirve a alguien en el futuro, descargué NetBeans con jdk 8 en el link y todo me va sin errores.

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que en realidad la clase que tratas de usar ya no existe.

**No debes usar pack200 ya que esta fue removida del SDK**

```
java.util.jar.Pack200
java.util.jar.Pack200.Packer
java.util.jar.Pack200.Unpacker
```

**podrías usar instalar una versión menor y configurarla en Netbeans sin embargo no considero esto recomendable.**

---

Esta es la [**información oficial**](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/336):

**Motivación**
Pack200 es un esquema de compresión para archivos JAR, introducido en Java SE 5.0 por JSR 200. Su objetivo es "disminuir los requisitos de disco y ancho de banda para el empaquetado, la transmisión y la entrega de aplicaciones Java". Los desarrolladores usan un par de herramientas, pack200 y unpack200, para comprimir y descomprimir sus archivos JAR. Hay una API disponible en el paquete java.util.jar.

**Hay tres razones para eliminar Pack200:**

Históricamente, las descargas lentas del JDK sobre módems de 56k fueron un impedimento para la adopción de Java. JDK 8 fue la última versión comprimida con pack200 en el momento de la compilación y sin comprimir con unpack200 en el momento de la instalación. En resumen, un consumidor importante de Pack200, el JDK mismo, ya no lo necesita.

Más allá del JDK, fue atractivo comprimir las aplicaciones del cliente, y especialmente los applets, con Pack200. Algunas tecnologías de implementación, como el complemento de navegador de Oracle, descomprimirían los JAR de applet automáticamente. Sin embargo, el panorama para las aplicaciones cliente ha cambiado, y la mayoría de los navegadores han dejado de admitir complementos. En consecuencia, una clase importante de consumidores de Pack200 (applets que se ejecutan en navegadores) ya no son un controlador para incluir Pack200 en el JDK.

Pack200 es una tecnología compleja y elaborada. Su formato de archivo está estrechamente acoplado al formato de archivo de clase y al formato de archivo JAR, los cuales han evolucionado de manera imprevista por JSR 200.

Answer (score 1):

Me funcionó una [solución de Felistrix que encontré en el sitio en inglés](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60771107/how-to-fix-error-while-installing-netbeans) (traducción del editor):

> Lo solucioné así:
>
> 1. Desinstalé JDK 14
> 2. Instalé JDK 13.0.2
> 3. Instalé Apache NetBeans
> 4. Instalé JDK 14
> 5. Abrí C:\Program Files\NetBeans\netbeans\etc\netbeans.conf y cambié el path al JDK
> 6. Desinstalé JDK 13.0.2
>
> Ahora NetBeans corre con la JDK 14.

Comment: De hecho cualquier version anterior a la 14, funciona bien